# Wrong date if date is wrong on computer using DateTime.UtcNow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to add posted date of product to database. I am using `DateTime.UtcNow` but it shows wrong date if date is wrong on computer. How can I solve this problem?

I have "prodpostDate" column in the "product" table and its type is nvarchar.

```
 DateTime aDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
 item.prodpostDate= aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
  _context.Products.Add(item);
```

Comment: Some sample input, expected output, and actual output would be helpful. Also, why store a `Date` type as a `string`?

Comment: @RufusL because i converted it to string to remove time

Comment: @Aytac Then store it as a date instead of a datetime, it'll strip the date automatically. But one should NEVER store dates as string, there is simply no good reason to do so.

Comment: @Alejandro i have done it but there was date and time because of  `DateTime.Now()`

Comment: @Aytac C# DateTime always include time, but you "truncate" it when inserting to DB with the proper type. Using a string is a sure way of getting problems down the road.

Comment: And anyway, I think that for auditing purposes, having the time in addition to the date is an important thing to have, as it could be used for exact time comparison if a problem arises.

Comment: Get the date directly in the database when inserting data.

Comment: Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date is not wrong. The date is exactly what it should be. When you call Now functions, it pulls the date and time from the computer that executes the code. If the date is wrong on the computer, you need to update it/change the timezone.

Expanding on the comment below:

If you want the date and time regardless of a users local settings, you cannot get the date time from their local machine which is what happens if you call a Now function from code ran on the client. You need to make a call to a different source to get it. If you are using an API, you could make a call to it from your client to get the current date and time. Even better than that, if you end up sending a request to the server for an update, just don't send a date time and let the server get it and populate it. Or if you are doing a database update, let the database get the date time on update/insert.

Comment: I want to show exact date if users change time on their computer.

Comment: The solution to that is simple: if the user's system time is unreliable, don't rely on the user's system time. Use a trusted source, like the database server or a time server.

Comment: @madreflection Problem is that I am new to programming and don't know how to do it.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your answer.